# What is the difference between module and table in Lua?

Tags: lua

Is a module just a table that can be required in Lua?

What is the real difference between the two?

Comment: Usually, a module is a code (in a separate file) that constructs this table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module is a library. A collection of functions, and possibly some global data.

It is implemented using tables. The table would store the module's functions and/or data, but the module is not a table. It's a concept, a logical construct.

For a table to be considered a "module", it must participate in the modules system. To be registered/referenced within the modules system, be found when user `require` it, etc...